# Magento 2 How to override extension frontend template file?

Tags: magento2, overriding

I have one extension and it has the following file:
app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/templates/**test.html**

I want to override that specific file in my theme:
app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[ThemeName]

So how can I do that please help me.

Answer (score 5):

It will be overridden in the following path.

**app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[ThemeName]/[Namespace_Module]/templates/test.html**

For example the file is

**app/code/Qasim/test/view/frontend/templates/test.html**

It will be overriden in the following path

**app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[ThemeName]/Qasim_test/templates/test.html**

Comment: Hi @Qasim Let me try this and after it I have to RUN any command?

Comment: @Rajan you need to remove the pub/static var/ and run sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy after this

Comment: still it generated from the extension file app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/view/templates/test.html

What can I do so it will be generated from the app/design/frontend

Please help me if you have already fixed it.